# --debug command line argument in Python

Tags: python, command, argparse

When I introduce to the command line "--debug" argument I need to set variable "debug", from my python script, to the value 1.

I've tried something, but I have to write "--debug=1" to the command line to set variable.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--debug", default=2)
```

When I run the command:

```
python script.py --rev1=1.2 --rev2=1.5 --debug
```

my variable "debug" should have value 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested to know whether a certain command line flag has been passed to your script, you'd set the [`action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) argument of `Argument.add_argument` to `store_true`.

```
parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true')
```

Then `parser.parse_args().debug` will have the value of `True` if `--debug` was present and `False` otherwise.

```
$ python script.py
parser.parse_args() returned Namespace(debug=False)
$ python script.py --debug
parser.parse_args() returned Namespace(debug=True)
```

Comment: `action='store_const'` along with `default=2` and `const=1` could be used to set values of 1 or 2.  `store_true` is a subclass of `store_cont`.